# Permission denied while running native commands in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, permission-denied, tomcat9

I'm trying to build an webapp as wrapper for youtube-dl. I'm calling the youtube-dl command using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` but all I'm getting is permission denied saying `File system is read-only`

And I'm passing the working directory while executing command like `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("youtube-dl ...",null,workingDirectory)`

Permission for the workingDirectory is changed like below
`drwxr-xr-x 1 tomcat tomcat    0 May 13 08:21 Folder`

Even tried ProcessBuilder instead of RunTime results same issue and tried other commands such as `touch` to create file, but the result is same. got `touch: cannot touch 'a.txt': Read-only file system` error

I'm using tomcat9 - 9.0.16-3ubuntu0.18.04.1, Java8 - 1.8.0_242, Ubuntu - 18.04.1 and tomcat is installed via apt-get

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You ***want*** to edit your [`catalina.policy`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/security-manager-howto.html#Configuring_Tomcat_With_A_SecurityManager).

Comment: Security manager is not enabled in tomcat and I've tried enabling security manager and given permission, still getting same result. But I can able to read the files without any issue, problem occurs only when I trying to write file. As my understanding If it's an security manager issue I would've got SecurityException (Correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Could anyone help? I'm stuck in this stupid problem for days ‍♀️

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your file system went to read only mode.. Please get that server reboot..

Comment: I understand it is in read only mode whenever executing native commands, How do i change it to read-write mode for native commands

Comment: I'm able to execute the commands as tomcat user without any issue